# portfolio optimization sorting efficient solutions C#

Tags: linq, list, removeall

I have the following problem to solve:

Let H be a set of portfolios. For each portfolio `i` in `H` let `(ri,vi)` be the `(return,risk)` values for this solution.

For each `i` in `H` if there exists `j` in `H` (`j` is different from `i`) such that `rj>=ri` and `vj<=vi` then delete `i` from `H`. because `i` is dominated by `j` (it has better return for less risk).

At the end `H` will be the set of undominated efficient solutions.

I tried to solve the above problem using linq:

```
 H.RemoveAll(x => H.Any(y => x.CalculateReturn() <= y.CalculateReturn() && x.CalculateRisk() >= y.CalculateRisk() && x != y));
```

But I wonder if there exist a more efficient way, because if `H.Count()` is of the order of ten thousands, then it takes a lot of time to remove the dominated portfolios.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Christos

Comment: I got lost somewhere between j and vi. Can you post some code without abbreviations which shows your problem?

Comment: H is a list of Portfolio classes. Each portfolio consists of assets with each asset having a weight, w, which is a number in [0,1]. All the weights sum to 1. Using two methods of portfolio class, we can estimate it's risk and it's return. So each portfolio has a pair of (return,risk). The problem that i want to solve is to find all the portfolios of a list of portfolios, which are not dominated. In order to understand the concept of dominated portfolio, we need to introduce the above abbreviations.

Comment: In case you need some further explanation to the above, let me know. Thanks again Milen.

Comment: If `H` is a list of Portfolio objects, then name it `portfolios`. Same for other names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be caching the Risk/Reward. I can't tell if you are by your code sample, but if you aren't you need to transform the list first.

Once you've done that, it makes sense to order the list according to the risk. As you increase risk, then, all you have to check is that your reward is strictly greater than the best reward you've seen so far. If it's not, you can remove it. That should dramatically improve performance.

Unfortunately, I'm not feeling clever enough to think of a way to do this with pure LINQ at the moment, but this code segment should work:

(Disclaimer: I haven't compiled/tested)

```
var orderedH = (
  from h in H
  let reward = h.CalculatedReward()
  let risk = h.CalculatedRisk()
  orderby risk ascending
  select new {
    Original = h,
    Risk = risk,
    Reward = reward
}).ToList();

var maxReward = Double.NegativeInfinity;
for (int i = 0; i < orderedH.Count; i++)
{
  if (orderedH[i].Reward <= maxReward) {
    orderedH.RemoveAt(i--);
  }
  else {
    maxReward = orderedH[i].Reward;
  }
}

var filteredPortfolio = orderedH.Select(h => h.Original);
```

Comment: Andrew thank you for your help ! It works as it would be expected. The complexity of your algorithm is O(orderedH.Count()), linear to the size of the list. Unfortunately using linq the complexity was quadratic to the size of the list. Thanks again !

Comment: @Christos: It's probably more like O(H ln H), since you have to sort it first... but it's still better than O(H^2)!

Comment: Andrew, you are bloody right! Unfortunately, my enthusiasm, when I saw the algorithm, made me wrong. Thanks for your notice !